# How to port iOS categories to Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I know most categories (using methods) can be ported using C#'s extension methods. But I hit a road block... I'm trying to port an iOS library to Xamarin, but I have this code here:

```
var specialKeyboardDistanceFromTextField = textFieldView.keyboardDistanceFromTextField
```

`textFieldView` is a `UIView` and the property `keyboardDistanceFromTextField` is defined here:

```
public extension UIView {

    /**
    To set customized distance from keyboard for textField/textView. Can't be less than zero
    */
    public var keyboardDistanceFromTextField: CGFloat {
        get {

            if let aValue = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kIQKeyboardDistanceFromTextField) as? CGFloat {
                return aValue
            } else {
                return kIQUseDefaultKeyboardDistance
            }
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kIQKeyboardDistanceFromTextField, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea on how to replicate that. The closest I've come was https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.CategoryAttribute/ but the property is not there when I write the code (C# is not aware of that property, which makes sense...).

So, if I need to create regular Get and Set methods as mentioned by @Sweeper. How can I use the `objc_getAssociatedObject`?

Note: I'm not looking to create bindings, please. I want to port it. Thanks.

Comment: "C# is not aware of that property" which property?Just create extension methods `GetKeyboardDistanceFromTextField` and `SetKeyboardDistanceFromTextField`.

Comment: This is a property: `keyboardDistanceFromTextField `

Comment: Yes that is a property. I know that you can't create extension properties in C# but can't you create two extension methods called `GetKeyboardDistanceFromTextField` and `SetKeyboardDistanceFromTextField`?

Comment: @Sweeper sure, but the question is where would that value be stored? I'd still need a property inside the UIView class to store that value. Wouldn't I? Thanks.

Comment: But isn't `keyboardDistanceFromTextField ` a _computed property_? You can't add stored properties in extensions in swift anyways. You don't need to store anything. Do you mean that you can't find the functions `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject`?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, I see your point. And no, I didn't mean that, even though I haven't looked for those functions yet... could you please post that as answer with an example on how you would use that objc_set and get using a local property? Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm not so familiar with Xamarin and I don't know how to call objc_set/get... I was just trying to make your question clearer for other people.

Comment: @Sweeper ok, thanks. I'm going to edit it